# How do I change pathname of a file in a zip

Tags: macos, zip

Is there a shell command or other way to alter the pathname of a file stored in a zip in OSX?

Comment: Just to be clear: You want to move a file from one directory to another within a zip file?

Answer (score 0):

You definitely can't directly change pathnames within a zip using built in software, and there doesn't seem to be an obvious choice in terms of third-party software.

The easiest way in the short term would probably just be to extract the zip, make the necessary changes, and then create a zip archive from that, overwriting the original zip.

Alternatively, if you can manage to get [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) working on a Mac, 7zip's file manager lets you rename files and folders stored in a zip, without you having to extract and re-archive.